# GCP Autoscale Down Protection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

So I have a set of long running tasks that have to be run on Compute Engine and have to scale. Each task takes approximately 3 hours. So in order to handle this I thought about using:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-cloud-pub-sub-long-running-tasks

Architecture. And while it works fine there is one huge problem. On scale down, I'd really like to avoid it scaling down a task that is currently running! I'd potentially lose 3 hours worth of processing.

Is there a way to ensure that autoscale down doesn't scale down a VM with a long running / uptime?

EDIT: A few people have asked to elaborate my task. So it's similar to what's described in the link above which is many long running tasks that need to be run on a GPU. There is a chunk of data that needs to be processed. It takes 4 hours (video encoding) then once completed it outputs to a bucket. Well it can take anywhere from 1 to 6 hours depending on the length of the video. Just like the architecture above it would be nice to have the cluster scale up based on queue size. But when scaling down I'd like to ensure that it's not scaling down currently running tasks which is what is currently happening. It being GPU bound doesn't allow me to use the CPU metric.

Comment: What metric are you using to scale up?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm using pubsub num_undelivered_messages. Scaling up works fine. It's just when it scales down. I worry about it getting rid of instances have been running for quite some time.

Comment: I don't think auto scaling is the solution. Your situation is task based. I would look at Google Cloud Tasks for this.

Comment: @JohnHanley updated!

Comment: My comment stays the same. Use Cloud Tasks and not autoscaling via Pub/Sub.

Comment: I had no idea you could use Cloud Tasks with GPU and non-containerized application. If you'd like to reply below I can make your answer as correct

Comment: Award the answer to Raul Bautista. His answer is correct, and he added links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should probably add more details about what kind of task you are running. However, as @Jhon Hanley suggestion, it worth to take a look of [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview) and see as well the following documentation that talks about the [scaling risks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/manage-cloud-task-scaling).

Comment: I tried to update. Perhaps you can take another look

Comment: Another possibility is running your tasks as [jobs in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/jobs) with a [cluster with GPU](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus) in [autoscale mode](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#gpu_pool).